# HDD error or system hardware failure on aging home server?

Tags: server, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I have ubuntu 20.04 desktop machine that I'm using as a home media server.

I have the system installed on an SSD.  There is also a Raid 5 mdadm array with 3 4TB seagate Iron Wolf Pro drives that are 4TB each.

I originally built the server in 2013 so its age is starting to show.  Here is the motherboard:
https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16813130646?Item=N82E16813130646

Seems like I have been getting mdadm array failures in the array more often over the last year or so.  I assumed it was due to aging disks, but now I'm thinking the motherboard SATA ports or controller are going out.  Is there a way to know for sure?

It had been running fine with the side panels off for a month or so after my last attempt to fix things - I replaced all SATA cables with new.  But then over the weekend I had to shut it down during a power failure (server is on battery backup).  So I figured I might as well screw the side panels back on to the case while I had it shut off.  I was trying to be careful not to nudge the cables.  I booted it up yesterday and everything seemed fine...  But then this morning I got email notification of a failure in the array.  I looked and one of the IRON Wolf Pro drives - the newest - less than 1 year old, which happened to be an RMA replacement from the first one that also failed with many SMART errors.

Here is some info from the 'Important' log:
[Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYyQK.png)
and more:
[More Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRXE0.png)

output from mdstat:
johnw@JW-MediaServ:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sdc1[0] sdd1[1](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16813130646?Item=N82E16813130646)
7813769216 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
bitmap: 5/30 pages [20KB], 65536KB chunk

```
unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: I think you already know you have drive failures.

Comment: if I already knew that why would I have made this post?